# Sound Mixer on Windows to mix sound over several output devices

Tags: windows, audio, audacity, mixer, volume-mixer

I am looking for software that primarily let me mix sound over all devices, sound-cards etc.

For example to have sound mixed over a blue-tooth headset and laptop speakers.

It should also be possible to see where which apps (Like SKype for example) want to send sound where.

(This seems to be a bit different from what one usually looks for in an audio mixer).

Anything within Audacity?

Comment: Maybe something like [VAC](http://software.muzychenko.net/eng/vac.htm)?

Comment: Perhaps - but it is PAY

Answer (score 2):

For Windows 7, Stereo Mix like this:

> > 1. Open Sound panel
> > 2. Select Speakers as the default playback device
> > 3. Go to the "Recording" tab
> > 4. Right click and enable "Show Disabled Devices"
> > 5. A recording device called "Wave Out Mix", "Mono Mix" or "Stereo Mix" (this was my case) should appear
> > 6. Right click on the new device and click "Enable"
> > 7. Right click on the new device and click "Set as Default Device"
> > 8. Double click on the new device to open the Properties window
> > 9. Go to the "Listen" tab
> > 10. Click on the "Listen to this device" checkbox
> > 11. Select your HDMI device from the "Playback through this device" list
> >
> > And you're done, the drawback is that you won't have a microphone selected as default recording device, but for what concerns me I couldn't care less.

Source: http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-sound/is-it-possible-to-have-speakers-and-hdmi-play-at/4563a5f8-4be4-4463-b312-eff594a9ae49

If not, then probably VAC (payware) from comment.

It might depend on audiocards and drivers.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is something within Audacity. It's a bit hard to find, but it's actually even [documented](http://manual.audacityteam.org/o/man/tutorial_recording_computer_playback_on_windows.html) properly.

Here's the crucial bit:

[image]

Select your speaker device and Audacity will record everything that you hear through your speakers.